# Information from a third table using a linking table

Tags: mysql, adonis.js

I have three tables:

### classes

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | name1 |
| 2 | name2 |

## users

| id | email |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | email@1 |
| 2 | email@2 |

### campaign_user

| user_id | campaign_id | class_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 4 | 1 |
| 2 | 4 | 2 |

1. "classes" is the table I am doing the query on.
2. "users" which contains the user's email and his role.
3. "campaign_user" which is the linking table that has user_id and class_id and campaign_id.

I need to make a call in MYSQL that finds the user that belongs to the campaign and the class that has the rule equal to 4 (which is in the campaign_user table) and attach his email to the class
How do you do it in Adonis?

[image]

I expect to get back:
`[{id:1,name:name1,email:email@1 },{id:2,name:name2,email:email@2 }]`

id - Belongs to class.

name - Belongs to class.

email - Belongs to user.

Comment: *I have three tables* Provide this in CREATE TABLE form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution:

in Models/class.ts

```
@manyToMany(() => User, {
pivotTable: 'campaign_user',
localKey: 'id',
relatedKey: 'id',
pivotForeignKey: 'class_id',
pivotRelatedForeignKey: 'user_id',
onQuery(query) {
  query.where('campaign_user.role', 4).select('email', 'phone', 'username')
  },  
})
public managerDetails: ManyToMany<typeof User>
```

in campaign model:

```
  @hasMany(() => Class)
  public classes: HasMany<typeof Class>
```

And when I use it then I created the function:

```
public async classesIndex(): Promise<Class[]> {
const c: Campaign = this
await c.load('classes')
for (let i = 0; i < c.classes.length; i++) {
  await c.classes[i].load('managerDetails')
}
return c.classes
}
```